# Serializing Entity object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, entity-framework, serialization

This is the object I try to serialize:

```
public class EmailAttachment
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Filepath { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    public int EmailID { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual ReceivedEmail Email { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my serialization code:

```
        var attachments = unitOfWork.EmailAttachmentRepository.Get(e => e.EmailID == emailID);
        return Json(attachments, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The problem is that although I put `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute, `Email` property of `EmailAttachment` is still serialized. I can see entity log in the console, when attachments are fetched first there is no fetching of `Email` becuase lazy loading is enabled but when `return Json(attachments, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` is executed then for every attachment in list `Email` is fetched from database, and this is propagated on properties of `Email`.

How can I stop this? I want only `EmailAttachment` without its virtual properties...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable lazy loading when you've created your context, I would suggest modifying your `Get` method to accept another `bool` to enable/disable lazyloading:

```
var attachments = unitOfWork
    .EmailAttachmentRepository.Get(e => e.EmailID == emailID, lazyloading: false);
```

Then where you create your context:

```
using(var ctx = new MyContext())
{
       ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = lazyloading;  //false
       ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also did this with Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false, do you know what is the difference between those two?

Comment: @Aleksa Proxies are used to automatically detect changes, fix relationships and enable lazyloading. If you need them for read-only purposes (like you do) it might give a performance boost to turn proxies off. But if you only want to disable lazy loading (not change tracking), you should leave proxies on.

Answer (score 1):

`IgnoreDataMemder` works for different stack.

In you case you should use  [`ScriptIgnore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx) Attribure